# What is going on here?

Tags: discussion

Motorcycle randomly loses power

- https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/close/19357

I am completely baffled.  This question is in the close cue.

The cited reason is, too broad.

I could go on a rant but there is not real benefit.  I will say, this is ridiculous.  Troubleshooting is a component of the process with a technical problem whether it's SuperUser, serverFault or this site.  We MUST become more helpful.

Perhaps if the person who closed the question could let it sit for a couple of days and see what happens before they bring the hammer down...I just find this a bit of a quick reaction.  The OP is engaged in responding to questions so that means suggesting some edits or adding/removing components of the question is entirely possible.

Again, I'm a bit shocked....

Comment: [because we are mean to new users :(](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1626/85)

Comment: Wasn't me this time! But I agree, this is a thoroughly researched and organized question with plenty of continued input and support from OP. No reason to close even from the tightest of ***holes :P

Comment: Too Broad or Too Specific... It is like trying to pin the tail on the donkey sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Please note, the close queue is a quite democratic tool. Voting to close a question is an opinion of a single user and regarding his reputation, it's a valuable privilege to do so!

But a question wont get closed unless 4 other users (or a moderator) vote the same way within a few days as close votes expire. And that's where the review queue is good for: Indipendent opinions from indipentend users.

As you can see, 3 leave-open votes were recieved and therefore the question got not closed from within this queue. I would tag this question with [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) :)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Then I can not really grasp your issue here. What was the question? _[What's going on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyoutEHpPAU)?_ ;-)

Comment: @DucatiKiller - I think your question is answered here. It has to do with the opinion of the person who threw the the question into the review queue in the first place by putting a closed vote on it. I totally agree with you the close vote person's opinion is wrong in this instance, but it is their opinion. Should the question be in the queue? No. Should someone be entitled to their opinion? Absolutely. We have to let people do their thing, but we can also countermand when it's wrong by voting to keep it open. It is the reason we have checks/balances on the site.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say this, but this was me. I voted to close it as a duplicate of [this rather generic question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/820/why-is-my-motorcycle-losing-power-when-accelerating?rq=1).

**Why?**

[When the question was originally asked](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/revisions/32209/1), I thought it was rather vague as the make and model was not given, so I voted to close it as too broad. It was a week or so ago, and I was reviewing first posts. I can't remember if I flagged it as a duplicate as well as too broad, as there was not enough information at the time. The rather generic question that I suggested has seven answers at the time of me writing this, which I thought would be rather useful to the OP as how the question was in it's current state.

I didn't intend for the question to be closed, I just wanted the OP to improve the question, and alas, he did, but this was after I voted to close it, and it got into the queue.

**TL;DR, I'm sorry. I voted to close it before new information was added, so it was in it's first or second edit. I felt the question was too vague at this time as no make or model was provided.**

**Now that there have been several edits it is a good question, and I would probably ask this same question if I saw the question in the queue.**