# How do I deal with new questions that aren't good at the time of me reviewing them?

Tags: discussion, review

In the first posts review queue, there are several questions that I believe are not very good, but after I vote to close them, but the question then is edited and improved.

What should I do in this case? [I don't want to make the same mistake as here.](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1645/what-is-going-on-here?cb=1)

If this is the case what is the point of the first questions queue?

Comment: I will say, I appreciate that people are worried about such things. It shows me (and others I assume) people are taking the time to think about what they are doing, which means they care about the site. Thank you for asking such a question and worrying about the outcome.

Comment: The point of the queue is to guide you toward helping new users ask a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: remember, a lot of the new users here aren't huge nerds. Maybe the close vote should be deployed later rather than earlier.**

We've talked many times about how many of the new users here are complete novices to the SE format. Many of those same people are also almost completely ignorant of the basic vocabulary of our focus.  Obviously, this will make it difficult to phrase an easily answered question: if you don't even know the words, you won't be able to describe the symptoms with a lot of detail....

My suggestion is still the same: do some of the work for the new users.  Describe the missing information, suggest some of the blanks that need to be filled in and basically be the person that you would like to meet when you self-consciously meet a bunch of people who seem to know much more than you do.

We've seen many times that, when we make that extra effort, we greatly improve the content of the whole site while also creating a population of impressed and grateful new users.  Remember, those new users are the people that we need to join up in order to get out of beta.

If none of that works out, the close button is always available as the option of last resort.

Answer (score 4):

As Bob says, try to make some suggestions in a comment for how they can improve it.

Also, if you're not sure on something, use the skip button - that'll pass it on to someone else to review...